# Drupal 8 - Programmatically disable or enable link on main navigation

Tags: php, symfony, drupal, drupal-8

This concerns Drupal 8.
I'm trying to manage a link item on the main navigation. I want to enable/disable an item, programmatically.
I searched but cannot find how to do that. I found MenuLinkManager, MenuLinkContent, but I can't do what I want.
Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you actually want to remove the link I would use [`hook_menu_links_discovered_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_menu_links_discovered_alter/8.2.x)

For example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_links_discovered_alter().
 *
 * @param array $links
 *   An array of links.
 */
function HOOK_menu_links_discovered_alter(array &$links): void {
  unset($links['machine_name_to_remove']);
}
```

Comment: In Drupal 9 this one generate an error for me TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuTreeStorage::save() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\DEV\espace2-navigo\web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuLinkManager.php on line 404 in Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuTreeStorage->save() (line 257 of C:\DEV\espace2-navigo\web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuTreeStorage.php).

Comment: I was trying to hide the 'standard.front_page' (Home) menu item

Comment: @AchrafJEDAY maybe put some debug code in MenuLinkManager to see why it's failing.

Comment: I posted a solution that worked for me and I also figured out that it is easier to create a new menu rather than to use the existing 'main-navigation' menu. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

To Disable/Enable Menu items means show/hide it. So, we can do it via below code in theme file

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_menu().
 */
function theme_preprocess_menu(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['menu_name']) && $variables['menu_name'] === 'main') {
    foreach($variables['items'] as $key => $item) {
      $path = $item['url']->toString();
      switch($path) {
        case '/menupath':
          unset($variables['items'][$key]); //Remove menu item
        break;          
      }           
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works with menu sub items.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me: tested with Drupal 9.3.9 (April 2022).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_links_discovered_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_menu_links_discovered_alter(&$links) {
  $links['standard.front_page']['enabled'] = 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. I was trying to disable a menu item, but hook_preprocess_menu wasn't working for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can install the module Special Menu Items
https://www.drupal.org/project/special_menu_items

Or do it in your theme_link function in your template.php

```
function myTheme_link($variables) {
  if ((isset($variables['path']) && ($variables['path'] == $_GET['q'] || ($variables['path'] == '<front>' && drupal_is_front_page())))) {

    return ($variables['options']['html'] ? $variables['text'] : check_plain($variables['text']));
  } else {
    return '<a href="' . check_plain(url($variables['path'], $variables['options'])) . '"' . drupal_attributes($variables['options']['attributes']) . '>' . ($variables['options']['html'] ? $variables['text'] : check_plain($variables['text'])) . '</a>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the menu from cache if you are going to alter it dynamically:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_preprocess_menu(&$variables) {
  foreach ($variables['items'] as $key => $item) {
    if ($key == 'depot_opm.document_demande_existant_tabs') {
      unset($variables['items'][$key]);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  // Disable the cache of the menu block.
  if($variables['derivative_plugin_id'] == 'tabs-documents') {
    $variables['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
  }
}
```